# How does one specify the equivalent of `--proxy-headers` curl argument into requests?

Tags: python-3.x, proxy, python-requests

I'm looking to pass some headers only into my proxies as I'm using requests, and I don't see a method to do it.

the urllib3.ProxyManager has a `proxy_headers` parameter, so I would assume there's a way to set it for the requests library - am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with a customized HTTPAdapter (for example like the following):

```
import requests

proxyheaders = { 'http://proxy.that.needs.header:8080/': { 'ProxyHeader1': 'SomeValue', 'ProxyHeaderN': 'OtherValue' } }

class ProxyHeaderAwareHTTPAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def proxy_headers(self, proxy):
        if proxy in proxyheaders:
            return proxyheaders[proxy]
        else:
            return None

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://', ProxyHeaderAwareHTTPAdapter())
s.mount('https://', ProxyHeaderAwareHTTPAdapter())
s.get(....)
...
```

You could also directly create and return a configured urllib3.ProxyManager if You overwrite the proxy_manager_for methos instead of proxy_headers if You like.
https://requests.kennethreitz.org/en/master/api/#requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter