# Python requests equivalent of '--proxy-header' in curl with SSL certification

Tags: python-3.x, curl, python-requests, ssl-certificate

Reference: [How does one specify the equivalent of `--proxy-headers` curl argument into requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440279/)

I am a newbie vis-a-vis Python.

I have a requirement, where a request to a destination(webpage) must go through a proxy server.

- I need to **pass headers to the "Proxy server"** (same as --proxy-header of curl)
- Need to add an **SSL certificate** (a '.cer' file) to read the passed headers to the proxy server(a 'Man In the Middle' scenario) **on CONNECT**.

The curl equivalent of my requirement is as follows:

```
curl -k --verbose --cacert /proxy/cert/folder/proxy-certificate.cer --proxy-header "header1: value1" --proxy 'http://localhost:8080/' 'https://destination.com'
```

I did come across a similar example [How does one specify the equivalent of `--proxy-headers` curl argument into requests?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58440279/). But I am unsure how to incorporate this with an SSL certificate.

**My Code:**

```
proxyheaders = { 'http://localhost:9090/': { 'header1': 'value1' } }

class ProxyHeaderAwareHTTPAdapter(requests.adapters.HTTPAdapter):
    def proxy_headers(self, proxy):
        if proxy in proxyheaders:
            return proxyheaders[proxy]
        else:
            return None

s = requests.Session()
s.mount('http://', ProxyHeaderAwareHTTPAdapter())
s.mount('https://', ProxyHeaderAwareHTTPAdapter())
URL = "https://stackoverflow.com/"
cert_file_path = "/Path/to/certificate/proxy-certificate.cer"
try:
    s.get(URL, verify=cert_file_path)
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

I get the following error:

```
HTTPSConnectionPool(host='stackoverflow.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:1056)')))
```

Answer (score 0):

THIS IS NOT A SOLUTION:

When i usually encounter certificate/verification errors, i just force it to not verify the certificate using the code below:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify false
```

Note that this is not usually recommended and i usually do it temporarily until i finish either running spicific script or downloading a library or so. If you want to try this and if it works for you, remember to turn it back on once done using the code below:

```
conda config --set ssl_verify true
```